# asynchttp and rhomobile

Tags: database, json, rhodes

How can i display JSON data in a rhomobile application without saving it to a database?

thanks

Comment: The question is unclear. What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

use
AsyncHttp

```
def index
   Rho::AsyncHttp.get(
            :url => "http://someurlx.com",
            :callback  => :parse)
end

def parse
    body= @params['body']
    @@json_data = Rho::JSON.parse(body)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

To display JSON data the best method is what I found [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoelements/rhoelements-tutorial#preloading-the-product-catalog)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to get json without callback url

```
@response=Rho::AsyncHttp.get(
            :url => "http://rhostore.herokuapp.com/customers.json"     
      )
json_parse=JSON.parse(@response)
```